# ListBox enable disable does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using ListBox control. Code is :

```
    <ListBox Name="documentList"  IsEnabled="{Binding WorkResultsModel.IsEnable,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkResultsModel.ImageCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                        Width="300" Padding="10" Height="200">
```

I am setting true/false property to IsEnabled attribute of the list box on button click. When we set false and clicking the list of item then items event working first time and then after showing disable the item. And same when we set true then items showing in disable mode and event does not work. How to fix this issue? thanks in advance.
Button Command code is:

```
private void ButtonClickCommand(object obj)
{ 
       if(status=="Edit")
           WorkResultsModel.IsEnable = true;
       else {
            WorkResultsModel.IsEnable = false;
        }
 }
```

And Property changed code is as follows:

```
   private bool _isEnable = true;
    public bool IsEnable
    {
        get { return _isEnable; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this._isEnable, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsEnable");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you Raising a `PropertyChangedEvent`after setting IsEnable value?

Comment: yes, I am using MVVM model

Comment: Then show us more relevant code (listbox binding,where are you setting/unsetting isEnabled..). We can't help without that

Comment: thans for reply. private void ButtonClickCommand(object obj){ if(status=="Edit")WorkResultsModel.IsEnable = true; else {WorkResultsModel.IsEnable = false;}

Comment: Don't add any code as a comment. Better click in `Edit` in your question and add there all your relevant code.

Comment: Please check I have updated original question

Comment: Ok, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Can you explain a little bit what is the problem. You talk about disabled items. I don't really understand what is your issue

Comment: Hi, I think now sufficient information for understand the problem. Please provide need full solution.

Comment: my issue is when we set false and after that we click on item of list box then item is selecting and event will be fire and after that list is showing disable. This is a wrong way and this is  my problem. In another way when we set false the list is not showing in disable mode before clicking on the list box item and this is occurring same for true.

Comment: Sorry about my late response, but i've been busy. The first thing i would try is removing the `TwoWay` from binding. It has little sense in the case of `IsEnabled` for the combo to update the source. So try this: `IsEnabled="{Binding WorkResultsModel.IsEnable}"`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from code behind:

```
private void Button_Click_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   documentList.IsEnabled=!documentList.IsEnabled;
}
```

Comment: Its same as you set from coding or property attrribute. I am using MVVM model so directly controls not accessible.